# Razor Pass Model with a long string to a Controller causes an exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using an MVC Razor to send a model from view to controller and everything works ok until I send a long string (about 3000 characters). It causes the exception: `"The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long."`

This is my code:

```
<iframe width="700" height="400"
        src="@Url.Action("_CKEditorIFrame", "EditorMessage", Model.MyModel)">
</iframe>

public ActionResult _CKEditorIFrame(MyModel model)
{
    return PartialView("_CKEditorIFrame", model);
}

public class MyModel
{
    public int Id { get;set; }
    public string MessageText { get; set; }
}
```

How could I fix it without changing the `web.configuration maxQueryString` value.

Comment: Since you're not mentioned what method being used, I assumed your request sent using GET method, which limited to certain number of characters. Without changing `maxQueryStringLength` in web.config, you may require POST method when sending that large amount of string.

Comment: @Tetsuya Yamamoto You are probably right. I also wanted to change it to a post request but how to do it? The problem is that it is an iframe. I found articles that I should add name attribute and then at the _CKEditorIFrame view to use BeginForm, am I correct?

Comment: Which one you want to do: postback that `iframe` contents to controller or simply POST-ing controller action method and put responses to the `iframe`? If the latter is fit with your need, you can use HTML attributes `new { @target = "iframename" }` on `BeginForm` and `<iframe name="iframename" ... />`.